# Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/webkit/android-jsc/maven-metadata.xml Issue in react native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not resolve org.webkit:android-jsc:+.
> Required by:
> project :app
> > Failed to list versions for org.webkit:android-jsc.
> > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/webkit/android-jsc/maven-metadata.xml.
> > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/webkit/android-jsc/maven-metadata.xml'.
> > Read timed out

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that you are using `mavenCentral` repository instead of `jcenter`

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.webkit/android-jsc

Answer (score 4):

[JCenter is going to shutdown](https://blog.gradle.org/jcenter-shutdown) and now is READ-ONLY. And it is getting offline often causing issues with builds and pipelines.

#### In summary

You will require to update your `android/build.gradle` file to use `mavenCentral()` instead of `Jcenter()`.

As per Gradle documentation, JCenter is a mirror of Maven Central, so all of your dependencies should be there.

> JCenter is a central artifact repository, like Maven Central. Software
> projects use JCenter to distribute their software to other people.
> JCenter also serves as a mirror for Maven Central, so any dependencies
> available on Maven Central are also available on JCenter (but not vice
> versa).

#### A few things to consider:

- In case it is a **library** (e.g node_modules/react-native-appsflyer), pointing to Jcenter, that is giving you an error... I would advise you to check the library giving you an error has updated a new version with a fix. In case so, update to the new
  version to get the changes.
- In case **the library doesn't have versions with the fix**, if you are building in React-native using npm packages, you could potentially take advantage of `patch-package` [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package). Because there will a possibility the libraries have not yet released the update removing JCenter from `build.gradle`.

##### Applying the patch

You can apply the changes yourself using the Patch Package library. Documentation added in the end for reference.

1. Go to `node_modules/library-with-error/android/build.gradle`
2. Change `jcenter()` to `mavenCentral()`
3. Run: `npx patch-package library-with-error`
4. Git add, commit and push

#### Personal notes:

- I did advise the full removal of `JCenter` instead of adding MavenCentral() to the top because of the **shutdown** and that JCenter is often getting offline and giving timeout errors.

> Based on the current timeline, builds that use JCenter will be able to
> resolve dependencies until *February 1, 2022* without changes. After
> that date, *there are no guarantees that you will be able to build*
> your software if you continue to use JCenter."

- Also, Gradle is discouraging the usage of JCenter.

> "To discourage new projects from using JCenter, we will be removing
> JCenter from our samples and init templates. The new default will be
> Maven Central. Gradle itself has no inherent tie to JCenter or Maven
> Central, so you can always switch any other repository of your choice.
> This change will be effective with the next Gradle release – Gradle
> 7.0."

- In case of **dependencies (pom, jar)** are not added to Maven, here [are instructions on how to add](https://maven.apache.org/repository/guide-central-repository-upload.html). Add that to the PR with discussions to collaborate.

#### Useful Links

- Add `--use-yarn` to `patch-package` command in case your project uses [Yarn](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package).
- Documentation using [Patch package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package).

Answer (score 2):

[image]

The gradle icon is on the right.

Answer (score 1):

Turn off your wifi and then build again.

Comment: Instead of doing this you can enable Gradle offline mode in Android Studio. Open the Gradle pane (it's a the right side, if you don't see it do View -> Tool Windows -> Gradle at the menu bar), then click the icon Toggle Offline Mode.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: It actually worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got error after upgrade RN from 0.63.2 to 0.64.3

> Could not resolve org.webkit:android-jsc:+.
> Required by:
> project :app
> > Failed to list versions for org.webkit:android-jsc.
> > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://maven.google.com/org/webkit/android-jsc/maven-metadata.xml.
> > Could not get resource 'https://maven.google.com/org/webkit/android-jsc/maven-metadata.xml'.
> > Could not GET 'https://maven.google.com/org/webkit/android-jsc/maven-metadata.xml'.
> > Connect to maven.google.com:443 [maven.google.com/172.217.163.46] failed: connect timed out

I fixed it by downgrade gradle-6.7-all.zip (comes from RN 0.64.3) to gradle-6.2-all.zip (comes from RN 0.63.2) in `android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`.